# Class method points to other method of other class

Tags: c++, pointers, c++14

i was wondering if is possible make that a method of class points to another method of other class:

consider this:

```
// Class Foo:

class Foo
{
    static int GetA(int a);
    static int GetB(int b);
};



int Foo::GetA(int a)
{
    return a * 2;
}

int Foo::GetB(int b)
{
    return a * 4;
}

// Hooking class methods:

class HookFoo
{
    static int HookGetA(int);
    static int HookGetB(int);
};

int(HookFoo::*HookGetA)(int) = (int(HookFoo::*)(int))0x0; // (0x0 Memory address) or for example: &Foo::GetA;
int(HookFoo::*HookGetB)(int) = (int(HookFoo::*)(int))0x0; // (0x0 Memory address) or for example: &Foo::GetA;
```

I know it's possible do some like:

```
int(*NewHook)(int) = &Foo::GetA;
```

but how i can do for declare the methods into of a class?

Comment: is it not feasible to simply do `static int HookGetA(int n) { return Foo::GetA(n); }`? Its not clear to me what you are trying to do

Comment: you can not redeclare/reassign functions, but you can use use function pointers (as you demonstrated) within `HookFoo`

Comment: No, the problem is that it is for use with memory addresses, i can't do this, the form that i posted is a simple example.

Comment: alright, also if these are static functions they don't need (shouldn't) be scoped to the class, they are just `int (int)` functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use function pointers.
Ex:

```
class A {
public:
    static void say_hello() { cout << "Hello\n"; }
};

class B {
public:
    static void(*hook)();
};
void(*B::hook)() = A::say_hello;

int main()
{   
    B::hook();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is more or less what you tried to achieve (minimal, working example):

```
class Foo
{
public:
    static int GetA(int a);
    static int GetB(int b);
};

int Foo::GetA(int a)
{
    return a * 2;
}

int Foo::GetB(int b)
{
    return b * 4;
}

class HookFoo
{
public:
    using FuncType = int(*)(int);
    static FuncType HookGetA;
    static FuncType HookGetB;
};

// Initialized with Foo::GetA
HookFoo::FuncType HookFoo::HookGetA = &Foo::GetA;
// nullptr'ed
HookFoo::FuncType HookFoo::HookGetB = nullptr;

int main() {
    HookFoo::HookGetA(0);
}
```

For the methods in `Foo` are static, you can use a simple function pointer type to refer to them. You don't have to use (and can't use actually) a member function pointer in this case.
The using declaration helps to have a more readable code.
When you have correctly initialized your *hooks*, you can invoke them (thus the pointed functions) as you can see in the `main`.
I added a couple of visibility specifiers for your methods and data members were all private.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to hook into functions at a specific address, use a function pointer. You can't reassign functions like that

```
// typedef your function pointers, it makes the syntax a lot easier
typedef int(*FHook)(int);

class HookFoo
{
  static FHook HookGetA;
  static FHook HookGetB;
};

// assign to address
FHook HookFoo::HookGetA = (FHook)0x1234;
FHook HookFoo::HookGetB = (FHook)0x5678;
```

Of course its your job to make sure the addresses are correct.

the explicit function pointer types would be as such:

```
class HookFoo
{
  static int (*HookGetA)(int);
  static int (*HookGetB)(int);
};

int (*HookFoo::HookGetA)(int) = (int(*)(int))0x1234;
int (*HookFoo::HookGetB)(int) = (int(*)(int))0x5678;
```

Comment: yes good, but you know if there is another way to do this without typedef?, thanks a lot.

Comment: @nikomaster, you can write the type out by hand every time. Not `typedef`ing is however a most masochistic exercise in code obfuscation.

Comment: @nikomaster why would you be against `typedef`?

Comment: @vu1p3n0x because i want know how do it manually without using a data type.